# Unable to create window alert in Angular 7 (click) function

Tags: angular, angular7

I am unable to create a Chrome alert dialog when clicking on a button.

```
<button mat-raised-button matStepperNext color="primary" [disabled]="formGroup.invalid" (click)="window.alert('Thanks for your submission!')>Submit</button>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can not access "window" from the component.html file.

Instead, try creating an alert function in your component.ts file like so:

```
alert() {
  window.alert('test');
}
```

Then run the `alert()` function:

```
<button mat-raised-button matStepperNext color="primary" [disabled]="formGroup.invalid" (click)="alert()">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your component.ts file you can say

```
window = window;
```

And then use `window` in your component.html as you would anywhere else

```
<button (click)="window.alert('Hello world')">
 This is a button
</button>
```

Comment: Such a confusing suggestion. window is a reserved word and this a window to 1million errors

Comment: Are you able to elaborate where this is error prone? I'm not saying that it's not.

Comment: We never should use reserved words, that's why they are reserved. Sometimes the compiler will not give the error, but it will provoque runtime error, very difficult to debug, because it will not be at the same line as the used word. Sometimes, it will make a snowball of errors